# Deserialize JSON entities to POJO with ID references

Tags: java, json

Lets say we have the following JSON example:

```
{
  "teachers": [{
    "id": "abc",
    "payment": 10,
    "name": "xyz",
    "clases": ["1", "3"]
  }, {
    "id": "qwe",
    "payment": 12,
    "name": "xcv",
    "classes": ["1", "2"]
  }],
  "classes": [{
    "id": "1",
    "room": 7
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "room": 1
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "room": 2
  }]
}
```

I would like to deserialize it to Java objects (getters/setters ommited):

```
class Teacher {
    private String id;
    private double payment;
    private String name;
    private List<CLassRoom> classRooms;
}

class ClassRoom {
    private String id;
    private int room;
}
```

As you see, we have a references here. I know I can deserialize it with `Jackson` (and would like to) but the problem is that I cannot touch DTO itself (so annotations are not possible, would also like to avoid wrappers (many classes)). Also, it would be nice if the "configuration" of deserialization was in separate file (`json schema` for example). I would also like to avoid some tags given by user - he should only pass me the values. Moreover, he should know where is the error, if he made some mistake.
Also, it would be nice if I could manipulate name of field in json (some clients may have different habits).

I didn't find anything which satisffied all of above requirements(entity reference and error handling are the most important). However - I just have heard about json schema, so maybe it provides such functionality (but I didn't find it though). Any helpful reference/example/lib? I will appreciate any help.

Just to be correct - imagine that the given json is a *RELATIONAL* database snapshot of the instance. I just want to create whole entity like the hibernate (or actually JPA) does :)

Comment: With Jackson you should be able to write your own custom serializers and deserializers. That would allow you to do almost everything you need. Since your JSON contains 2 sibling lists while your DTO contains nested ones, you'd need to write some transformation anyways. This could be JSON-to-JSON first but you could write a deserializer as well and do it in one go.

Comment: Yes, I know but the problem is that then I need to handle errors like missing field by myself. Also, then I need to do something like read all following entities, and then manually match them in other entity. This is not so extensible. I am working in OSGi so i can create a bundle, but as I said, i would like to reduce the compiled code as much as it is possible.

Comment: With the newer versions of Jackson, all you mentioned can be done with the correct configuration, without having to write a custom serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Well, the structures don't fit anyways so you need to do something. You could use something like normalizr for the JSON->JSON conversion (entities to nested) and then Jackson for JSON->DTO. However, you'd need to handle missing properties as well (either by telling Jackson to do it or by simple means in your deserializer). What I'm not sure of but I'd suspect it should work with some effort is mixing standard and custom deserializers for multiple parts of your JSON.

Comment: @GuilhermeMussi ok, but two questions:
1) is that configuration can be in external file (with some format like json)
2) what with validation, and will it be different from manually connecting entities?

Comment: @Thomas Good idea, but there is one problem - I need that entities have the same references in the runtime... when I will just copy values to ids in json, then i will lose reference. Also, it would be easier to just collect them and find by id.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. add jar of import org.json.JSONObject.

2. JSONObject object = new JSONObject(list)
    2.1 object.has("teachers") if it is exists
    2.2 JSONArray teacherArray = (JSONArray) object.get("teachers");
    2.3 JSONObject teacherJsonObject = teacherArray .getJSONObject(0);
    (if you have more than jsonobject in json arrary then itrate it.)
    2.4 if(teacherJsonObject .has("id"))//you can check existence like this.
        String id=teacherJsonObject .getString("id");
        String payment=teacherJsonObject .getString("payment");
        String name=teacherJsonObject .getString("name");
```

Comment: Ok, it is logic, but now imagine that I have more than 20 classes like this (really few more), different clients (and dtos) and it may change with time (open-close principle). Does not work in that way :/.

Comment: if you have prior knowledge of class names then make a arraylist of class name and iterate it by checking its existence in payload that is json data.if it is present then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but it's a working one.

Let's create a Parser class like the following:

```
public class Parser {
    private List<Teacher> teachers;
    private List<ClassRoom> classes;

    public void parse() {
        for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
            for (String classRoomId : teacher.getClasses()) {
                for (ClassRoom classRoom : classes) {
                    if (classRoom.getId().equals(classRoomId)) {
                        teacher.getClassRooms().add(classRoom);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modify your ClassRoom class to have a getter on the id field:

```
public class ClassRoom {
    private String id;
    private int room;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And your Teacher class to get the Ids of classes AND the classRooms references:

```
public class Teacher {
    private String id;
    private double payment;
    private String name;
    private String[] classes;
    private List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();

    public String[] getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public List<ClassRoom> getClassRooms() {
        return classRooms;
    }
}
```

If you use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, you could then just parse your JSON like that:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Parser parser = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Parser.class);
parser.parse;
```

Now, every teacher will have their classRooms correctly referenced.

Comment: As I said... I cannot modfy my entities. And they have getters/setters (but it is not required for Jackson btw). Nevertheless - Thank you

Comment: Can you create new classes to wrap this ones?

Comment: I have a lot of dtos so it would be realy hard. More to say, I need this as one of my endpoint (another is database for example), so it would be very hard to mantain (moreover, I have multiple domains in the single project connected with each other in some way... but not at dto level).